# Is posible to create column dynamicaly based on query select using group by before

Tags: mysql, query, pivot

Good afternoon, i want to ask about MySql query.

I have the initial data from first query as pict below (can dymically) base on where clause using this query `SELECT company, discipline_name from tb_data WHERE nfc_id <>"" and valid_start = '2023-07-12' group by category ORDER by category asc`.

[image]

And from second query i get the data as pict on bellow using this query `SELECT company, discipline_name, count(global_id) AS Total from tb_data WHERE nfc_id <>"" and valid_start = '2023-07-12' group by company,category ORDER by category asc;`.

[image]

Then the result i wanted like pict on below.
[image]

my question is, how to create dynamicaly column like the result i wanted. because the count of column sometimes is changed base on valid_start where clause. Using stored procedure or how?

Thank You,
Regards

Comment: There are a lot more examples of `[pivot-table]` in stackoverflow.com .  However, the cross-tabs is not discussed much.

Comment: Consider writing the "pivot" using http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot . However, embelish it to get the horizontal and vertical totals, too.

Comment: And please fix the `SELECTs` to have the same column names as the images.

Comment: Hai Rick, correct. Thats looks like pivot table, and i can do it with use select (sum if). But my Goal is find the way to automatically create column based on category selected on first query. I will read your sugested link first. Thank you so much.

Comment: In terms of RDBMS table describes a `type` or `class` while rows of table are an instances of that type or class. With dynamic columns you'll get a class of dynamic structure that would be very hard to work with. If this table is just for reports you can form them on the client side with more suitable language. If you intended to create such tables in the database my advice is to revise your approach.

Comment: My link shows how to discover the columns needed from the data.

Comment: hello Rick James.
Correct, workly nice from your link. Thank You.